# SQL Query Terminology?

Tags: sql, terminology

What are the correct terms to differentiate "modifying queries" (update, delete, etc) and "non-modifying queries" (select, etc)?

A university project requires a list of all queries used by the system and I would like to put appropriate headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying queries = [Data Manipulation Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language).

Non-Modifying queries are mostly also considered part of the DML.
Quote from the above link:

> The purely read-only `SELECT` query statement is classed with the 'SQL-data' statements and so is considered by the standard to be outside of DML. The `SELECT ... INTO` form is considered to be DML because it manipulates (i.e. modifies) data. In common practice though, this distinction is not made and `SELECT` is widely considered to be part of DML.

Answer (score 1):

"Modifying queries" (update, delete, insert, merge) and "non-modifying queries" (select) are all [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language): Data Manipulation Language.

The for basic functions for data storage are [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). I don't know about a differenciation for modifying classification.